# Etymology of legal meaning of 'dispositive'

Tags: etymology, legalese

Since Prof. Eugene Volokh has observed its counterintuitiveness, what's an intuitive derivation?

> [Prof. Eugene Volokh:](http://volokh.com/2010/09/01/dispositive/) One way of remembering this is by looking at the stem, which turns out to be “dispose of,” as in “dispose of the question” (in the sense of “to deal with conclusively; settle”)
>
> **[dispositive (adjective)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispositive)** = 1. Relating to or bringing about the settlement of an issue or the disposition of property
> 1.2. (In US law) producing a final settlement or determination.
>
> [Etymonline for 'dispose'](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dispose&searchmode=none): late 14c., from Old French disposer (13c.) "arrange, order, control, regulate" (influenced in form by poser "to place"), from Latin disponere "put in order, arrange, distribute," from dis- "apart" (see [dis-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dis-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ponere "to put, place" (see [position](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=position&allowed_in_frame=0)). Related: Disposed; disposing.

Since Etymonline lacks an entry for 'dispositive', and in view of Prof. Volokh recommendation above, I linked to 'dispose' instead, but it doesn't appear to explain this legal meaning?

Comment: If **dispositive** is simply an adjective derived from **dispose**, for which you list the etymology above, I do not understand your problem.  You have the etymology right there.  And "put in order" is perfect meaning.  Remember, this is an old legal term (Merriam-Webster has the first known use in 1618), created and used by people familiar with both Latin and French, not least because "Law French" was used in English courts well into the 17th century.

Comment: Up, the way you are phrasing these questions is attracting the types of comments and answers which you don't find helpful.  What you're looking for, and therefore should be *asking* for, is a *mnemonic device* or memory-aid or trick to help you recall the meaning of new or unfamiliar words. Asking "*How did X evolve to become Y?*" just gets you answers which quote etymonline; asking "*What's the etymology of X*?" and supplying the pre-emptively supplying the etymology just gets comments like "*You already have the etymology, what are you asking?*". [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] In the future, just ask for a mnemonic device. I'm not sure the community will accept such questions as on-topic, but asking on-topic questions of etymology so that the questions aren't closed doesn't help if it doesn't get you the answers you need anyway. And if EL&U doesn't accept requests for mnemonic devices, maybe ELL will.

Comment: With all that said, let me try to rephrase the mnemonic device Prof Volokh was providing, and the other answers here are emphasizing: ***dispositive* -> *dispose* -> *throw out* -> *be done with forever***. A *dispositive* point allows the court to immediately *be done with the case forever*, and most often by *throwing the case out of court* (i.e. dismissing the plaintiff's arguments as baseless).

Comment: In legal contexts, a fact (or a set of facts taken together) is "dispositive" when it has  strong bearing upon how the matter is to be disposed; the fact is more than relevant, it brings about or effects the disposition. The *-ive* suffix means "having the tendency to, being inclined to, having the quality of". I assume the OP's question is, How do we get from *-ive* to "having sufficient importance to effect a disposition".  Is that quality *inherent*?

Comment: For comparison, note in Fr for the first part of the definition... [dispositif d'un arrêt](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dispositif) used as a noun; it is not the _ratio_ of the decision but rather its final "dispositions"(1) so to speak or indeed how it practically brings about the settlement of the issue. Otherwise imho the verb should be related to the prerogative(2) the owner of property has, to dispose of his property, in the Civil Law tradition; so here there's the core property meaning - I can consume the thing; then there's the contracts meaning of transfer(3).

Answer (score 1):

OED confirms Eugene is correct:

> **Etymology**:  In Caxton < French dispositif, -ive (13th cent. in Hatzfeld & Darmesteter), < Latin type *dispositīvus , < dispositus , past participle of dispōnĕre to dispose v.: see -ive suffix. In later use probably immed. from Latin or on Latin analogies.
>
> 3. Having the quality or function of directing, controlling, or disposing of something; relating to direction, control, or disposal.
>
> dispositive clause (Sc. Law): the clause of conveyance in a deed, by which the disposition of the property (see disposition n. 4) is expressed.

["dispositive, adj. and n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2014. Web. 22 November 2014.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/55126)

It's about disposing. I don't find that counter-intuitive, so I can't really come up with a more intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene, as quoted, is misleading at best: the root is *dispose*, not *dispose of*. The noun from the latter is *disposal*; from the former we get (and still use) *disposition*, meaning 'arrangement', from which the legal meaning (as well as 'temperament' and the others your dictionary gives) derives by extension.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure Eugene is *misleading* so much as *imprecise*. He was not speaking as linguist to a room full of etymologists, he was speaking as a law professor to his students, and trying to give them an easy way to remember the meaning of a new piece of legalese.

Comment: Most interesting! If I understand you're saying _dispositive_ comes from _disposition_ (from _dispose_, as in trans. I gather). But then would that mean that all dispositions are dispositive? More practically, would you then say that what the Professor disposes of in the last sentence of his note, that _decisive_ factor, as when the Court said _it's dispositive of the issue_, is a higher value "arrangement" as opposed to the factor that settles the case? I'd argue it is not very useful to try to describe both functional reasoning and tranfer of property with some overarching adjective.